# Install Elixir to System

Tags: package-management, programming, bashrc, language-support

How can I install Elixir on Ubuntu 13.04 so that I can easily use it from the command line and update it easily by cloning git.

I have installed Erlang 16 by getting package from here [Erlang Downloads](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp)

There is a source elixir git here https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir I can clone it and use it by navigating to the bin directory but how do I set it up so it is available to the system from bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `bin` directory from your clone to your `PATH`.

For example, if the git clone is in your home directory, use:

```
export PATH=~/elixir/bin:$PATH
```

Although looking at the source, it looks like what you should really be doing is installing it:

```
$ cd ~/elixir
$ git pull
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

This will install elixir in /usr/local/bin, which should already be on your `PATH`.

Comment: So to update do I just repeat that process everytime pull, make, make install?

Comment: Yes, that will get you to the latest version in git each time.

Comment: Don't forget to do `make clean test` if you updated from master, because it can be broken or old compiled libs can interact the new build

Answer (score 2):

There is also [a PPA available](https://launchpad.net/~bigkevmcd/+archive/elixir). The following steps have been tested successfully on Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy), but should work on Raring and Precise without any modification:

For Erlang (see https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang/):

- Add repository:

  ```
  wget http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
  sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
  ```
- Install package:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install erlang
  ```

For Elixir:

- Add repository:

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bigkevmcd/elixir
  ```
- Install package:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install elixir
  ```

Comment: the ppa repo is no longer available, fund a new one `ppa:tsutsu/elixir`

Comment: Seems like Elixir is now also part of the Erlang solutions repo. From the official Elixir website:
1. Add Erlang Solutions repo: `wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb`  
 2. Run: `sudo apt-get update`  
 3. Run: `sudo apt-get install elixir`

Comment: This does not seem to give you the elixir 1.2 though